# Calculate the same point in different aspect ratios

Tags: geometry

I am trying to calculate the exact same point on two images. Say I have two images that are the same, however the images have different aspect ratios and thus different resolutions.

Image 1 has an aspect ratio of 16:10 and a resolution of 1920x1080. The exact pixel I need as at 1600x900.

Image 2 has an aspect ratio of 37:18 and a resolution of 2960x1440. How can I work out what the exact same pixel would be?

Comment: There is not a one-to-one correspondence between the pixels.  I don't think it makes sense to talk about "the same exact pixel."

Answer (score 0):

This is just a question about proportionality in each axis separately, and has nothing to do with the aspect ratio.

In the first image the the first coordinate of the point is $1600/1920$ of the way along the first axis, so in the second image it will be the pixel at
$$
\frac{1600}{1920} \times 2960 = 2466.7.
$$
You want the pixel nearest that coordinate.

The same kind of calculation finds the second coordinate.

Separate issue. I was surprised that the aspect ratio does not match the pixel ratio for the first coordinate:
$$
\frac{16}{10} = 1.6 \ne \frac{1920}{1080} \approx 1.8.
$$
(They do match for the second.)